# Latex suddenly stops working in jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-lab

Looks like some sort of load library error. I don't see many problems in the debugger though. Tried restarting, upgrading, relaunching chrome, hard-reload etc.

Comment: I've just seen in the console (where jupyter lab was launched) a 404 /static/components/MathJax/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf/MathJax_Script-Regular.otf